# Можно ли как-то сделать вход на сайт по отпечатку пальца? Как получить доступ к сканеру из браузера?

Tags: javascript, php, веб-программирование

Просто из браузера в телефоне. Подскажите, в какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 3):

К сканеру доступ из браузера никто не даст, вообще такого не видел, но если бывает, то скорее всего это работает немного по-другому. Локально на девайсе есть хранилище ключей, по отпечатку из хранилища вытаскивается ключ для сайта и шлется запрос на сервер, сервер авторизует по ключу и дает доступ